# phpMyAdmin Magento Price Update

Tags: mysql, magento, phpmyadmin

I have backup of my Magento database, somehow I need to update the database that is on the live site with the prices from the old database backup I have exported `mg_catalog_product_index_price.sql` but not sure if there are any more tables.

I need to somehow import that table onto the live site database, when i tried to just use the import tab in phpMyAdmin I got this error.

`#1062 - Duplicate entry '108-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: You have to export your table as "UPDATE" not "INSERT".

Comment: @Tim I have just tried that but I am now getting this error http://pastebin.com/D6JWTkWs

Comment: why are you trying to `ALTER TABLE` if you need just to re-enter data?

Comment: @Tim Im not sure still new to MySQL, basically I have the backup and I need the table `mg_catalog_product_index_price` on my local copy to update and overwrite the info in table `mg_catalog_product_index_price` on the live site with the info from the backup

Comment: Do you need to overwrite only data or do you need to restore table structure also?

Comment: @Tim It just needs the table to have all the date from the backup to the live db

Comment: Why did you make a backup of the index table ? The prices it contains are regenerated each time the products prices get reindexed (eg, from the indexes list in the backend), based on the actual prices that come from many different other tables

Comment: @blmage so what do I need to export and import?

Comment: @blmage do you know which tables they are?

Comment: This depends on what kinds of products you have, but at least `catalog_product_entity_decimal`, that in fact contains all values corresponding to the decimal attributes of each product (so not only the prices but the cost, weight, etc..).
If you have custom options with prices, the tables are `catalog_product_option_price` and `catalog_product_option_type_price`.
For the configurable products, the options prices are stored in `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing`.
And there are also different tables for bundle products and tier prices. Knowing that catalog rules can affect prices too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that "Structure" is unchecked ad "Export type" is set to "UPDATE":

[image]